# Find the volume using the disk method

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

Let $R$ be the region bounded by the following curves. Let $S$ be the solid generated when $R$ is revolved about the $x$-axis. Find the volume using the disk method.

$$\begin{align*}
&y=\sqrt{\ln x}\\
&y=\sqrt{\ln x^2}\\
&y=1
\end{align*}$$

I cannot seem to get the right answer for this. I am getting the result of just $\pi$ and that is incorrect. I first found where the two natural log equations intersect and that is at $1$. So that would be my lower limit. I found my upper limit by setting the first equation equal to the last equation ($= 1$). That gave me my upper limit of $e$. I removed the $\pi$ outside of the integration and then squared both of the natural log equations. Therefore, I would be integrating $\ln(x^2)-\ln(x)$ because the $ln(x^2)$ equation is above the other one. After integrating, I got the answer of $1$. I then multiplied this by $\pi$ to get the answer of $\pi$. However, the website is saying this is incorrect. What did i do wrong?

Comment: You may prefer to write $ \ \sqrt{2} \cdot \sqrt{\ln x} \ $ in place of  $ \  \sqrt{\ln (x^2)} \ $ ...

Comment: @julien: The details of the computations are mostly there. The problem is actually with the setup.

Answer (score 2):

The region $R$ has three sides.  Between $1$ and $\sqrt{e}$, the disks have outer radius given by $\sqrt{\ln(x^2)}$ and inner radius $\sqrt{\ln x}$.  However between $\sqrt{e}$ and $e$, the disks have outer radius given by $1$ and inner radius given by $\sqrt{\ln x}$.

See diagram:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

With the disk method you need two integrals, one for the part of the region to the left of the point of intersection of $y=1$ and $y=\sqrt{\ln x^2}$ and one for the part to the right. That intersection occurs where $1=\ln x^2=2\ln x$, i.e., at $x=\sqrt{e}$. On the interval from $x=1$ to $x=\sqrt{e}$ the region $R$ lies between the curves $y=\sqrt{\ln x^2}$ (at the top) and $y=\sqrt{\ln x}$ (at the bottom); on the interval from $x=\sqrt{e}$ to $x=e$, however, it lies between $y=1$ (at the top) and $y=\sqrt{\ln x}$ (at the bottom).

The disk method is a poor choice here: the shell method sets up more neatly, requiring only a single integral.

Comment: Many textbook exercises are based on making the less-desirable choice for volume integration, though, in order to press students to practice integration techniques or partioning of regions in the plane (and thus, to appreciate the convenience of some methods over others)...

Comment: @RecklessReckoner: I know, and I have always despised that practice: it’s horrible pædagogy. I have always instructed students to ignore stupid artificial requirements of that kind.